# Drupal Event/Calendar Module not storing event time

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-6, calendar, module

I have installed a fresh copy of Drupal 6 on an Xampp server. Within that install is a collection of modules for creating an event calendar. There's actually a great instructional video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO4TeEydtMs for getting all the necessary fields up.

So far everything is working except... the events won't store the time as stated in the edit field. No matter what I do in the edit mode as admin or otherwise the time always says 12pm and the event on the calendar says "All Day".

I know this is pretty obscure but I figured why not try and ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What Date module are you using for the event dates? Is there an "All Day" option that is accidentally selected?

(I would just put this in a comment... but I don't have enough reputation to comment on questions yet :) )

Comment: I ended up doing a clean install and fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is to make sure your sitewide time settings are properly configured. You can find them under /admin/settings/date-time.